# Access and Run main class method from another class

Tags: java, user-interface, methods, mainclass

I have a problem finding a way to execute a method for printing in my main class, from the other class with `JButton`.

This is my `Mainclass` method I want to execute.

```
public void genInReceipt(Date in, String res) 
        throws Exception
    {
        log.debug("start printing...");

//      TOP
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, 'J', 0x4A}));
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, 'J', 0x4A}));
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, 'J', 0x4A}));
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, 'J', 0x4A}));
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, '@', 0x1b, 0x61, 0x01}));
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, '!', 0x08}));
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, 'E', 0x1b}));
        serialPort.writeString(String.format("%s\n", "PLAZA INDONESIA"));
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, 'J', 0x4A}));
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, 'J', 0x4A}));

//      PARAGRAPH 1 Still Fix(Add Parimeter)
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, '!', 0x08, ESC, 'a', 0x00}) + String.format("%s\n","    1343KZT/MOBIL"));// +  new String(new byte[] {ESC, 'E', 0x1B, GS, '!', 0x10, 0x01}) + String.format("        MOBIL"));
        serialPort.writeString(String.format("%s\n", "    PP6-ADE SILFIANAH"));
        serialPort.writeString(String.format("    In      : %s\n", df.format(in)));
        serialPort.writeString(String.format("    Out     : %s\n", "21 Jul 2016  17:00:00"));
        serialPort.writeString(String.format("    Duration: %s\n", "1 hours 29 minutes")); //Pakegate
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, 'J', 0x4A}));
        serialPort.writeString(String.format("    Sewa Parkir: %s\n", "Rp     6.000"));
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, 'J', 0x4A}));

//      BOTTOMLINE
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, 'a', 0x01}));
        serialPort.writeString(new String("TERIMA KASIH\n".getBytes()));
        serialPort.writeString(new String("ATAS KUNJUNGAN ANDA\n".getBytes())); 
        log.debug("              ... done");        
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {GS, 'v', 0x1D}));
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {0x1b, 0x64, 0x05}));
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {0x1d, 0x56, 0x42, 0x00}));
    }
```

And this is my GUI code

```
package unibit.embedded.parking;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class GUIPrinter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JButton button1 = new JButton();

        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(button1);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //What i have to add here to execute genInReciept method?
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I know it's something wrong with my code, can someone help me?

Comment: Instantiate the class. Call the method on that instance.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Or rather, two of them, each with a `main(String[])` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create instance of class with  `genInReceipt` and then call it like that:

```
  ClassWithGenInReceiptMethod o = new ClassWithGenInReceiptMethod();
  o.genInReceipt();
```

But firstly would be great to start read basses about java and programming itself.

Comment: I already make instance of genInReciept and call it..

But my genInReciept contain (Date in and String Res)

It Doesnt work,, 

Have any solution?

Thanks

Comment: `code`
public class GUIPrinter {
ParkingSimulator o = new ParkingSimulator();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JButton button1 = new JButton();

        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(button1);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                o.genInReceipt(in, res);
            }
        });

    }
@Divers

Answer (score 0):

What you need/want is pretty easy, you need an instance of the class and call the method...

## Example:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    //What i have to add here to execute genInReciept method?
    Mainclass mc = ...//get a MainClass or create a new instance like doing new Mainclass();...
    mc.genInReceipt(new Date() ,"???"); //I dont know what res is, since I can not find it in the method
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `GUIprinter` main class is in the same file as your `genInReceipt()` class. This is how I would do it.

```
public class GUIPrinter extends JFrame{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JButton button1 = new JButton();

    final Date date = new Date();// declare Date variable
    final String yourString = "Your String here";// declare String variable

    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(button1);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    genInReceipt(date,yourString);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    });

}

public static void genInReceipt(Date in, String res){
    // your code
}
}
```

Note: Your `genInReceipt()` class requires you to pass `Date` and `String` variables. Declare those variables and pass it to `genInReceipt()` class.

But if your `getInReceipt()` class is on another file. Follow the previous answers given. So to summarize how to do the previous answers.

1. Declare an instance of the class where `genInReceipt()` is located.
2. Call the `genInReceipt()`.

   ```
   public class ClassThatWouldCallgenInReceipt extends JFrame {

   ClassWithgenInReceipt o = new ClassWithGenInReceipt();// Here is the class where genInReceipt() is located
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();

   JButton button1 = new JButton();

   final Date date = new Date();// declare Date variable
   final String yourString = "Your String here";// declare String variable

   frame.add(panel);
   panel.add(button1);
   frame.setVisible(true);

   button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           o.genInReceipt(date, yourString);// Call genInReceipt() like this
       }
   });

   }
   }
   ```

And Here is `ClassWithgenInReceipt` where `genInReceipt()` class is  located

```
    public class ClassWithgenInReceipt{
    public void genInReceipt(Date date, String yourString){
        //your code
    }
    }
```

Note: I'm also fairly new to java. So I might did that answer with some errors. However if there are errors, please tell me for learning purposes :).